# JPA 2.1 StoredProcedureCall seems buggy for me

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.1

Accidently works or not and always keep saying even if the error is TOTAL other problem:

```
Parameter number 2 is not an OUT parameter
```

Even if the stored procedure is does not exist, like:

**Java call:**

```
StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("`sequence`.next_totally_not_existed_valsafafasf");
```

**Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter number 2 is not an OUT parameter
Error Code: 0
Call: { CALL `sequence`.next_totally_not_existed_valsafafasf(?, ?) }
    bind => [belso_ugy_iktato_szam_sequence, => 2]
```

**MySql Code:**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sequence`.nextval (IN seq_name varchar(100), OUT cur_val BIGINT)
BEGIN
    SELECT
        cur_value INTO cur_val
    FROM
        sequence
    WHERE
        name = seq_name;

IF cur_val IS NOT NULL THEN
        UPDATE
            sequence
        SET
            cur_value = IF (
                (cur_value + increment) > max_value OR (cur_value + increment) < min_value,
                IF (
                    cycle = TRUE,
                    IF (
                        (cur_value + increment) > max_value,
                        min_value, 
                        max_value 
                    ),
                    NULL
                ),
                cur_value + increment
            )
        WHERE
            name = seq_name;
    END IF; 
END $$
```

**Java Code:**

```
 entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("`sequence`.nextval);

        // set parameters
        storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("seq_name", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("cur_val", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
        storedProcedure.setParameter("seq_name", sequence_name);

        // execute SP
        storedProcedure.execute();
        // get result

        Long result = null;
        try {
            result = Long.valueOf((String) storedProcedure.getOutputParameterValue("cur_val"));
        } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
            return 0;
        }

        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager.close();
```

Is anybody experienced the same? Or am i missing something?!

Comment: why dont you give simple name for store procedure like nextSeqvalue ( without ` and . ) and try with that ?

Comment: Tried with numerous names, but it has a simple name: nextval()

Comment: your cur_val is not integer ?

Comment: It is Bigint, but can be converted to Long (like you can see later), i dont think it can cause issue...